# Is there any open source java library to convert FIX messages to json format?

Tags: quickfix

Quickfix supports converting a FIX message to XML however does not support conversion to json. The only reference I found related to this was at https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6xZVoYGImPOZGotUmVQOVBBMzA/preview.

Is there any open source library that already does this?

[EDIT] There are XML to JSON converters but this is a 2 step process and not efficient. Is there a library which just converts it directly to json format ?

Comment: Why not just use Quickfix to convert FIX to XML, and then convert XML to JSON? http://heshans.blogspot.com/2014/01/java-library-to-convert-xml-to-json.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you need to make a few decisions about how to handle certain cases.  For example:

- Do you emit FIX "enums" in JSON as names, or numbers?
- Do you support names for user-defined fields (and values)?
- Do you emit FIX field numbers as numbers in JSON, or names?
- What do you do about repeating groups?  FIX has them, but JSON does not.

I did make a program that did this a while ago, but it was Python and it's not open-source.  I leveraged the QuickFIX XML files which define the field numbers, names, and enumerated text values to make life easier.  I think I converted repeating groups into arrays somehow, but even then it doesn't work if you have user-defined fields in a repeating group (you must then edit your XML config file, or else there's no way to know where each group ends).

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking for Java specifically I wouldn't categorize this as an answer per se, but fix2json, a command line utility, is now available to help present native FIX(TV) message files as JSON:

https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/fix2json

full disclosure: author of fix2json, released through my employer.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel includes a converter : QuickfixjMessageJsonPrinter.java

This however only parses Camel Exchange objects. I adapted it to make it usable with quickFix Message objects :

```
public class FixToJson {

private static DataDictionary dataDictionary;

public static String fixToJson(Message message) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    QuickfixjMessageJsonTransformer renderer = new QuickfixjMessageJsonTransformer();

    sb.append(renderer.transform(message, "  ", getDictionnary())).append("\n");
    sb.append("}\n");

    return sb.toString();
}


private static DataDictionary getDictionnary() throws Exception {

    try {

        if (dataDictionary == null) {

            String pathToDictionnary = "/path/to/fixDictionnary/dic.xml";

            dataDictionary = new DataDictionary(pathToDictionnary);

        }

        return dataDictionary;

    }

    catch (ConfigError configError) {

        throw new Exception("Error while instanciating FIX DataDictionnary : "  + configError.getMessage());

    }
}
```

}

Don't forget to include

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-quickfix</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I haven't tested stand alone so you might also need to include

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```